# Stack Exchange Winter Bash has begun! Hats all around!

Tags: discussion

Hats have begun! As part of an attempt to spread holiday cheer, Stack Exchange has decided to do a winter hat bash.

so, you might see something like this when you login to Ask Ubuntu today:

[image]

Hats galore all around! So, go forth and earn hats.

And if you dislike hats, there is an opt-out button - just click the "i hate hats" link, and you won't see any hats.

Comment: Who *doesn't like hats???*

Comment: the possibility exists that someone might not like hats.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I don't see that jrg *wearing* his hat..

Comment: Dont like hats, but further moustache enhancements look cool!

Comment: One small doubt brothers . after collecting them what's next ?

Answer (score 9):

Finally Hats!

[image]